# unable to generate report in iText core java

Tags: java, netbeans, itext, report

I tried to use iText5 and iText7 to generate report but I got the same problem:
here is the code:

```
try{
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStrem("Repor.pdf"));
    doc.open();
}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
}
```

in line:

```
Document doc = new Document();
```

why it ask me to generate abstract methods?

also there is no method `.open();` in:

```
doc.open();
```

Comment: Most likely you `import` a wrong `Document` class.

Comment: I import import javax.swing.text.*;

Comment: @SweetGarl - You need to import `com.itextpdf.text.Document` and `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter` as well.

Comment: yes that's it the error is gone thank you very much @Arvind Kumar Avinash